# Flyout Item using AppShell navigation perform button click on activity mainpage.cs or secondpage.cs before navigating

Tags: android, maui

I need my flyoutItem to perform a programmatically clicked button click before it performs its AppShell route to the selected page.

(The code for the button works as intended from a legacy project)

I am only currently able to navigate correctly using flyoutitems, and click the button on the activity pages, but can't seem to get the flyoutitem click to load the data on the navigated TO page upon loading.

In this example I can click a button that saves the data and I can click the flyoutitem to navigate, but I want the flyoutitem to click the button and then navigate:

**mainpage.xaml.cs**

```
    public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    one.Text = Preferences.Get("One", "FIRST");
}

    private void savebtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    one.Text = j1.Text;

    Preferences.Set("One", one.Text);
}
```

**page2.xaml.cs**

```
    public page2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    tone.Text = Preferences.Get("One", "FIRST");
}
```

**AppShell.xaml**

```
    <FlyoutItem
    Title="HOME">
    <ShellContent
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
    Route="MainPage" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem
    Title="TWO">
    <ShellContent
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:page2}"
    Route="MainPage" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

**mainpage.xaml**

```
            <Editor
           x:Name="j1"
           Placeholder="Empty">
         </Editor>
        
        <Label
            x:Name="one"
            Text=""
            FontSize="32"/>

        <Button
            x:Name="savebtn"
            Text="SAVE"
            Clicked="savebtnClicked"/>
```

**page2.xaml**

```
        <Label
            x:Name="tone"
            Text=""
            FontSize="32"/>
```

As it is currently, the value passed appears to save, but requires the app to fully restart before it loads in the value that should have been saved to the key "one".

Comment: Could you please help elaborate your question clearly? What do you mean you can't seem to get the flyoutitem click to binding context to the actual button on the page before navigation begins and want the flyoutitem to click the button and then navigate.

Comment: Also, in `Maui`, the default implementation of the IPreferences interface is available through the `Preferences.Default` property,for more details, you can refer to [Set preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#set-preferences).

Comment: Ahhh thank you for the clarifying question. I re-read my post and edited it to now say:

"but can't seem to get the flyoutitem click to load the data on the navigated TO page upon loading."

Also for some reason I've been able to get the save preferences working without "Default" I have tried both ways and they both work how I want them to (I tested by making a button on the next page that is just "LOAD" basically so its like navigating with APPSHELL does not do a initialize or something the way I need it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I ended up using "OnAppearing" and then added my loading pref.get's and this worked.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page.onappearing?view=net-maui-7.0

Unfortunately this is just another project that I will not be learning MVVM for even though I badly want to start implementing it.

Comment: Excellent! You can add more details to your post and check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.